# HTML-JS : Plethora of buttons that each spawn a different form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

In my main page, i want to have a plethora of buttons (at least four) that each of will spawn a form with a different action each.

At any time only one form will be visible.

What is the best way to do this?

Should i creare four forms and when a button is selected will make all the other forms with `"visibility=hidden"` and just expose the one i want?

This is the code i used:

```
<html>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#editForm_1").hide();
        $("#editForm_2").hide();
        $("#editForm_3").hide();
        $("#editForm_4").hide();
            $("#btn_1").click(function(e) {
                    $("#editForm_1").show();
            $("#editForm_2").hide();
            $("#editForm_3").hide();
            $("#editForm_4").hide();

                });
        $("#btn_2").click(function(e) {
                    $("#editForm_1").hide();
            $("#editForm_2").show();
            $("#editForm_3").hide();
            $("#editForm_4").hide();

                });
        $("#btn_3").click(function(e) {
                    $("#editForm_1").hide();
            $("#editForm_2").hide();
            $("#editForm_3").show();
            $("#editForm_4").hide();

                });
        $("#btn_4").click(function(e) {
                    $("#editForm_1").hide();
            $("#editForm_2").hide();
            $("#editForm_3").hide();
            $("#editForm_4").show();

                });
        });
    </script>

    <body>

        <button id="btn_1" class="editbutton" > 1 </button>
        <button id="btn_2" class="editbutton" > 2 </button>
        <button id="btn_3" class="editbutton" > 3 </button>
        <button id="btn_4" class="editbutton" > 4 </button>

        <form id="editForm_1"  action="" method="post" name="editForm">  
            <input type="text" name="txtname" placeholder="1">
        </form>

        <form id="editForm_2"  action="" method="post" name="editForm">  
            <input type="text" name="txtname" placeholder="2">
        </form>

        <form id="editForm_3"  action="" method="post" name="editForm">  
            <input type="text" name="txtname" placeholder="3">
        </form>

        <form id="editForm_4"  action="" method="post" name="editForm">  
            <input type="text" name="txtname" placeholder="4">
        </form>     




    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The best way" is clearly subjective.
That said, note that setting `style.visibility = "hidden"` makes the element invisible but leaves empty space for it on the page.
For a cleaner UI, you might want to use `style.display = "none"`.

---

The algorithm for the solution suggested below is:

--- Start with all forms hidden (using CSS).
 --- Listen for any clicks in the document.
 --- Whenever a click targets one of the form-related buttons:
 ------ - Loop through all the forms, and for each form:
 --------- - Hide the form.
 --------- - Compare the form's `id` attribute to the (clicked) button's `data-form` attribute.
 --------- - If the form is a match for the button, show the form again.

---

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form"); // Remembers a list of all the forms

document.addEventListener("click", changeForm); // Runs the function on clicks

function changeForm(event){

  // Makes sure a form button was clicked before proceding
  if(event.target.classList.contains("formBtn")){

    // Remembers which button was clicked
    const formBtn = event.target;
    
    // Converts the `forms` NodeList to an Array so we can use the `.forEach` method
    const formsArray = Array.from(forms);    

    // `forEach` takes one argument: a function that we provide using `=>` notation.
    //    Our function (which `forEach` calls once for EACH form in `formsArray`)
    //    gets each form as an argument, hides the form, then possibly reveals it again
    formsArray.forEach(form =>{
      form.style.display = "none"; // Hides the current form

      // Relies on the button's `data-form` attribute matching the form's `id`
      if(form.id == formBtn.dataset.form){
        // Reveals the current form if it matches the button
        form.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
form{ height: 2em; width: 20em; border: 1px solid gray; display: none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div is="buttonsContainer">
    <button data-form="form1" class="formBtn">Form 1</button>
    <button data-form="form2" class="formBtn">Form 2</button>
    <button data-form="form3" class="formBtn">Form 3</button>
    <button data-form="form4" class="formBtn">Form 4</button>
  </div>
  <div id="formsContainer">
    <form id="form1">This is Form 1</form>
    <form id="form2">This is Form 2</form>
    <form id="form3">This is Form 3</form>
    <form id="form4">This is Form 4</form>
  </div>
</div>
```